# limit of the indicator function

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus B(0,n)} = 0$.

I don’t know exactly how to explain this mathematically. I would say that if n gets bigger than the ball $B(0,n)$ gets bigger and covers $\mathbb{R}^d$, thus near $\infty$ it equals $\mathbb{1}_\emptyset$ which is $0$. Is there a more mathematical way to express this?

Comment: Yes, here you are speaking about pointwise convergence. So fix any $x\in\mathbb R^d$ then you need to show that there exists $n$ big enough so that $1_{\mathbb R^d\setminus B(0,n)}(x) = 0$. Since for each $x$ you can find an $n$, you have shown the convergence to 0. This convergence however is not uniform.

Comment: and we have to show uniform convergence?

Comment: It's a little more nuanced than @frog is presenting it. You also need the fact that the balls centered at $0$ of radius $n$ are nested, i.e. $B(0, n) \subseteq B(0, n+1)$. It's not true in general that if you had a sequence of sets $X_n$ such that any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is contained in an $X_n$ implies $\lim_n 1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus X_n} = 0$. In your case, once $x\in B(0,n)$, $x\in B(0,m)$ for any $m > n$.

Comment: I understand your argument but I don't know exactly how to write all this into a nice proof for showing that the limit is 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comments above solves your question. However, I can write a proof for you if you are unfamiliar with calculus.

**Proof.**
For $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, if $n>\|x\|_2$, then
$$1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus  B(0,n)}(x)=0.$$

Hence,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus  B(0,n)}(x)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

The result is true and not true, depending on the definition of $\lim$. For functions, there are many different kinds of limits.
$\newcommand{\one}{\unicode{x1d7d9}}$

1. $\one_{B(0,n)^c}$ converges pointwise  to $0$: unpacking the defintion of $\one$,
   $$ \one_{B(0,n)^c}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |x|>n\\ 0 &|x|<n\end{cases}$$
   So for a fixed $x_0$, for all $n$ larger than $|x_0|$, we're in the bottom case, and therefore $\one_{B(0,n)^c}(x_0) = 0$. This shows the stronger statement that for each $x$, $\one_{B(0,n)^c}(x)$ is eventually equal to zero as $n\to\infty$.
2. $\one_{B(0,n)^c}$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ (or to anything else). This is because it is not Cauchy in the space of bounded functions with the supremum norm $\|f\|_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^d} |f(x)|$: for $n<m$ there are always points $x$ such that $\one_{B(0,n)^c}(x) - \one_{B(0,m)^c} = 1$ (take any point such that $|x| \in (n,m)$.) However, a variant of the first argument shows that $\one_{B(0,n)^c}$ converges "locally uniformly" to $0$; considered as a function on any bounded $K\subset \mathbb R^d$, $\one_{B(0,n)^c}$ is eventually the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any $\epsilon>0$, take any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m>\|x\|$. Then for all $n>m$, $|1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}(x)-0|=0<\epsilon$. Thus the pointwise limit of the said function is $0$ (notice that $m$ is dependent on $x$).

$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}|1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}(x)-0|=1 \nrightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So the convergence isn't uniform. [Here we use:  Let  $f_n,f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $M_n=\sup_{x \in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly iff $M_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$].

Now if $\{1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}\}_n$  uniformly converges to some other function then $\{1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}(x)\}_n$ would be a Cauchy sequence for **any** $x \in \mathbb{R^d}$. Choose $\epsilon=0.5~~~\exists~N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n>N$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ implies $|1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}(x)-1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,m)}(x)|<0.5$. Let  $p,q>N$ and take an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $p<\|x_0\|<q$, then $|1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,p)}(x_0)-1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,q)}(x_0)|=1$, a contradiction. Thus $\{1_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B(0,n)}\}_n$ isn't uniformly convergent to any point.

Comment: Specifically what you have shown is that it does not converge uniformly to zero. It does not follow that it doesn’t converge uniformly to something else (although the modification required is easy)

Comment: Thanks, corrected it.

Comment: you’re welcome; the argument i had in mind was is that uniform convergence to some $f$ implies pointwise convergence to $f$. Since pointwise limits are unique, the only possible uniform limit is the pointwise limit ie zero